# Keys 3, e, d and c do weird things

Tags: keys

I bought a Lenovo T410 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and GNOME 3.28.2.

The <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> keys do not work properly. This is their behavior:

- If I simply press them, nothing happens. In no application like libre or tusk do they work and they don't work in the terminal either.
- If I push <kbd>3</kbd> for longer, Ubuntu has a short flash as if it tries to start some app and then it spams "3".
- If I push <kbd>e</kbd> for longer, Ubuntu increases the sound and starts to spam "q".
- If I push <kbd>d</kbd> for longer, Ubuntu mutes the sound and starts to spam "a".
- If I push <kbd>c</kbd> for longer, libre wants to paste something into libre and if I agree to that I get spammed with "y".

Often the mouse freezes after that, so I cannot use the touchpad anymore. The right-click still works though. Sometimes the mouse does not freeze.

External keyboard works without problems.

Comment: All the malfunctioning keys are in the same column as if someone spilled a drink over those keys. If the keys send out lots of wrong signals that can cause the mouse and touchpad to freeze too. Putting the affected area of the keyboard in direct sunlight for a few hours might fix the problem.

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a hardware issue in that column of the keyboard's contact matrix.  Replacing the keyboard shouldn't cost a bunch and ought to fix it.